# Will ceil, floor and round meet loss-of-precision problems when converted to integers?

Tags: c++

I recall reading an example somewhere, which says converting double/float values to integer can lead to mistakes because of loss of precision. For example,

```
int a = 5.0000;
```

does not gurantee a to equal to 5, for actually 5.0000 may be stored as 4.9999 or something...

I wonder if using ceil, floor and round will run into similar problems. For example, consider the following code.

```
double a = ***; //some double-precision value
int b = ceil(a);
long c = floor(a);
long long d = round(a);
```

Are the values of b, c, d guranteed to be correct, provided that the value of a is in the range of integer values?

Update:

Thanks for the kind answers. Based on these answers, I have posted a follow up question.

[How seriously can ceil, floor and round functions amplify loss-of-precision issues, and how to eliminate such effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264084/how-seriously-can-ceil-floor-and-round-functions-amplify-loss-of-precision-issu)

Comment: How could they possibly be incorrect? What kind of error do you expect? Could you provide some example values for `a`, what outputs you expect and what outputs you suspect you might get instead?

Comment: If you say guarantee, then no. Consider `double a = 12345678910.5`

Comment: @Max Langhof Please see the edited question description.

Comment: For IEEE 754 binary floating-point numbers, `5.0000` is guaranteed to be precisely 5.

Comment: @Arne What if the double value is within the range of the integer type? My concern here is, say we have a double value a = 5.0001, then ceil(a) = 5.0000. Can further converting ceil(a) to an integer introduce an error?

Comment: you wont prevent loss of precision by rounding. I dont really understand the question, maybe you can clarify by replacing `***` with a concrete example

Comment: `Are the values of b, c, d guranteed to be correct` - specify what does "correct" mean. What is "correct" answer for `12345678910.5`? `floor(b)` - why do you `floor` an `int`?

Comment: with regard to rounding, lround and llround can be useful.

Comment: @cpplearner I recall reading an example somewhere else that says this is not the case. Maybe I am wrong. Anyway, under what circumstances do converting a double to an integer introduce a mistake, and do ceil, floor and round have such issues?

Comment: `under what circumstances do converting a double to an integer introduce a mistake` Please define what a "mistake" is? The answer could be always or never, depending how you define "mistake". How do you check for a "mistake"? Is `12345678910` or `12345678911` a "mistake" for `12345678910.5`?

Comment: @fdls2011 If I understand what you are saying correctly, then `floor` `ceil` etc are exact operations (given the range constraints you specified). Of course if the argument provided to them is inaccurate then the result will be inaccurate. But those operations themselves do not introduce any inaccuracies.

Comment: @john Suppose the integer type is int, not long or long long, can this problem be eliminated?

Comment: @fdls2011 Which problem are you talking about?

Comment: @john You seem to have deleted a comment, which said that larger integers have different representations in the system, and converting double to these large integers may induce a problem.

Comment: @fdls2011 would you consider `double a = 4.49999999999999999;` as, "within the range of integer?"

Comment: @fdls2011 I deleted the comment because it wasn't relevant, I was getting confused, see my answer below.

Comment: I usually write `int i = lround( ceil( d ) );` or `int i = lround( floor( d ) );` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/lround/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> actually `5.0000` may be stored as `4.9999`

This is not the case for IEEE floating point numbers ("floats" for short, I don't mean the `float` C++ data type). `5.0` is exactly representable as IEEE float, as are all integers that fit into the mantissa (i.e. with magnitude < `pow(2, N)` where `N` is the number of mantissa bits).

For values with magnitude larger than what fits into the mantissa, IEEE floats have no fractional component at all (but the distance between adjacent floats may be larger than 1). For example, the closest representable float to `pow(2, 100) + 1` is `pow(2, 100)` in IEEE floats with less than 100 bits of mantissa (such as the common 64 and 32 bit floats). `round`, `ceil` and `floor` will of course return `pow(2, 100)` (which won't fit into common integer types and might cause an error).

Further, `ceil`, `round` and `floor` do not introduce errors, but they might amplify existing errors. `5.0` is exactly representable, but computing `1.1 + 3.9` might not result in `5.0` because `1.1` and `3.9` are not exactly representable. In that case these functions may (correctly) round away from `5` as they are specified to, which may not be what your intention was. I suspect this is what the material you referenced was talking about and what has you confused: The "loss of precision" happened *before* rounding, with subsequent rounding amplifying that mistake (but not actually rounding incorrectly).

---

That said, C++ does not guarantee the IEEE float format (it's just by far the most common one). An implementation may use a completely different format.

Comment: All the floating point formats I know of (IBM 360, Prime minicomputer, all the VAX ones, IEEE) support exact representation of 5.0.  Of course, they all have different limits for the largest integer than *can* be exactly represented.

Comment: @Max Langhof Thanks for your answer. I have posted a follow-up question based on your answer (see the updated question description), and it would be very kind of you if you could help me with this new question.

Answer (score 3):

`floor`, `ceil` and `round` are exact operations.

However your code uses one of those functions followed by an integer cast. The integer cast is not an exact operation because not all integer valued doubles can be represented as actual integers.

However given the constraint you specified *provided that the value of a is in the range of integer values* then the cast will also be accurate.

However (this is a lot of howevers) nothing is going to fix inaccurate data in the first place. If your variable has the value 4.9999999 but the correct value is 5.0, then calling `floor` is going to give the incorrect value of 4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have posted a follow-up question based on your answer (see the updated question description), and it would be very kind of you if you could help me with this new question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will.

`floor` and `ceil` can not compensate for that not all integers are
representable. Consider:

```
float f = 16'777'217.5f;
cout << setprecision(20);
cout << ceil(f)  << endl;
cout << floor(f) << endl;
```

It will print `16777218` for both, if `float` is a 32bit IEEE 754

see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/894c8cb0ee517b16