# How seriously can ceil, floor and round functions amplify loss-of-precision issues, and how to eliminate such effects?

Tags: c++

I have previously posted a question concerning loss of precision issues for the C++ functions `ceil()`, `floor()` and `round()`. The link to the question is as follows.

[Will ceil(), floor() and round() meet loss-of-precision problems when converted to integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250160/will-ceil-floor-and-round-meet-loss-of-precision-problems-when-converted-to-int)

From the two answers I have received, I have learnt that these function themselves are exact, yet they can amplify existing loss-of-precision issues.

I wonder how greatly can these issues be amplified. Specifically, consider the following.

```
a = fun(b);
```

Here, `a` is an integer type value (`int`, `long`, `long long`, etc), `b` is a float type value (`float`, `double`, etc), and `fun()` is one of `ceil()`, `floor()` and `round()`. Note that in all the following discussions, I assume that there are no overflow or underflow issues.

Note that here, I assume that b is obtained by some other operation that may lead to loss of precision. For example, suppose I intend b to equal to 1.1 + 3.9 = 5, however, since 1.1 and 3.9 cannot be represented, b will not end up with 5.

I wonder to what extent can such issues affect the value of a. Specifically, how much will the correct value of a (that is, if there is no loss of precision for b) differ from the actually obtained value (that is, if there is potential loss of precision). Suppose we denote the correct value as a1, and the actual value as a2. It seems to me that under any circumstance, the following conclusions must hold.

1. If `fun()` is `ceil()`, then a2 equals to either a1 or a1 + 1.
2. If `fun()` is `floor()`, then a2 equals to either a1 or a1 - 1.
3. If `fun()` is `round()`, then a2 equals to a1.

My questions are, if we ignore overflow and underflow

1. Do the aforementioned conclusions always hold?
2. How to modify the code so that I can ensure that a2 always equals to a1, if I cannot fix the loss of precision of b?

Comment: If you're asking about C++, don't include a C tag — or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you are assuming that your error is `b` small. If the error in `b` was larger than 1.0 then none of your conclusions would hold. But presumably in practise the error in `b` is small and this is a reasonable assumption.

Conclusion 3 is wrong in all circumstances however. The correct result is that a2 equals a1 - 1, or a1 + 1, or a1. Suppose The correct value of b is 3.49999, the actual value is 3.50001 then `round` will give 4 when the correct result is 3. And vice versa if the correct value is 3.50001 and the actual value is 3.49999 then `round` will give 3 when the correct result is 4.

As for question 2 there is no simple answer to that. And it's impossible to answer the question in general terms, so some specifics on your actual problem are required. It sounds like you are trying to use inexact arithmetic when you need exact results. Maybe you need to switch to some kind of multiple precision arithmetic, there are several libraries out there for this, [MPIR](http://mpir.org/) for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One additional question, suppose I am doing a series of operations on double/float precision values. All the initial values, intermediate results and the final result are representable, then am I guranteed to obtain a precise result? For example, consider the code a = b * c + d / e. Suppose the values of b, c, d, e are precise, the exact values of b * c, d / e and b * c + d / e are all representable, am I guranteed that a is precise?

Comment: Yes I believe so. The IEEE754 standard guarantees that the result of any operation is the most accurate possible. So if the result is representable exactly then that is the result you should get. One caveat, I'm not sure what the guarantees are for library functions `sin`, `cos`, `sqrt` etc, possibly they might return inaccurate results.

Comment: Are you sure about this, *intermediate results are representable*? If so it's quite an unusual situation. I'm just checking that you realise that even simple fractions like one tenth are not respresentable as floating point numbers.

Comment: Actually I do believe that this is the case for me. Basically, my code is something like int_1 = int_2 * int_3 * log2(int_4) + int_5 * (log2(int_4) + ceil(log2(int_3))); Here log2 and ceil return double values. log2(int_4) should equal to an integer if calculated precisely (and I have checked this by comparing (int)log2(int_4), (int)(ceil(log2(int_4))) and (int)(floor(log2(int_4))), they share the same value). It seems that I cannot do much about the precision of  ceil(log2(int_3)), so I'll have to assume it is precise. And it seems that the rest of the intermediate results are representable.

Comment: Here int_1 to int_5 are all int type values.

Comment: So int_4 is always a power of two? I would imagine that the implementation of log2 takes powers of two into account and always returns accurate results for them (but I don't know that for sure). And I agree ceil(log2(int_3)) should always be precise but again I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Yes, int_4 is an input parameter that is requried to be a power of two.

Comment: @john At least the C++ standard only guarantees correctly rounded results for the four arithmetic operations `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`, as well as `sqrt` (plus some auxiliary functions like `std::fmod`, `std::modf` etc.). The trigonometric functions for example subject to the Table Maker's Dilemma (only recently solved for 64 bit floating point numbers) and are thus not required to give correctly rounded (i.e. within 0.5 ULP) results but are allowed up to 1 ULP of error.

Comment: @john (Although hardware implementations failed at that quite hard:  https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/).

Comment: @fdls2011 I see no reason why `log2` of a power-of-two integer should return an inaccurate result (that would be a big fail by the implementation), although I cannot find any documentation to support this. There may be cases where `ceil(log2(n))` computes the wrong result if `n` is very large: The 64 bit integer `(1 << 54) + 1` cannot be represented as a (64 bit) `double` (the closest one is `(1 << 54)`), so `ceil(log2(n))` may give you a wrong result. "May" because compilers are funky. But if you stay away from numbers that large it will all be fine.

Comment: @Max Langhof Thanks. In my application, I am confident that all integer values are representable by double.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase.

Assume that b_exact is an exact real number, that b is its floating point representation, a_exact is the result of func(b_exact) if computed in infinite precision, and a = func(b). You want to know how large |a_exact -a |, or maybe |a_exact - a|/|a_exact| can be.

Take a look at the tables [here](http://www.softelectro.ru/ieee754_en.html), section 7.4, of the maximum absolute and maximum relative error that the IEEE floating point representation makes.

Comment: Please see the updated question. I know that fun() (ceil, floor or round) results in exact values. What I am concerned with is, if b is not precise, to what extent can this inprecision be amplified by fun().